# How can an A* algorithm visit all nodes?

Tags: graphs, shortest-path, heuristics, a-star-search

Is it possible to find the shortest path and visit all the nodes in a graph by A* algorithm? If yes, how?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does the A\* algorithm visit every node?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/85413/does-the-a-algorithm-visit-every-node)

Comment: @ryan This question is **not** a duplicate of that question. Closely related? yes. Duplicate? not. That question is about whether an A* algorithm is supposed to visit every node (so that it will not miss the shortest path). This question is about how to define an A* algorithm so that it will visit all nodes.

Comment: @Apass.Jack I see your point. A* is a defined algorithm, I'm not sure what it means to "define an A* algorithm".  Do you mean to define a heuristic function such that these conditions hold?

Comment: If you just want an example of where this happens, suppose $s$ and $t$ are connected by a unique path and that there are no vertices outside this path in the whole graph.

Comment: You could also set the heuristic function to $h(v) = 0$ then let $t$ be the furthest node away from $s$.

Comment: To get your algorithm to visit all the nodes, you could just not terminate the algorithm when the shortest path from u to v is found.  Then, you will find the shortest path from u to each node as well.

Comment: @ryan, yes, I should have said, "as I understand, this question is about how to implement A* algorithm, i.e., how to define a heuristic function so that it will visit all nodes."